# Display overall progress for FileReference.load()

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, gsap

```
function files_select(e:Event)
{
    for (var k = 0; k < file_ref_list.fileList.length; k++) {
        var currFile:FileReference = file_ref_list.fileList[k];
        currFile.load();
        currFile.addEventListener (Event.COMPLETE, onDataLoaded );
    }
}
```

Now, How can i display overall progress for FileReference.load() in percentage. can i use LoaderMAX ?? or any other alternative.

Please Help.
Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

assign a ProgressEvent to you FileReference object.  the documentation contains sample code:

[flash.net.FileReferenece - ProgressEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#event%3aprogress)

Comment: thanx for the link, i know that fileReference has a Progress Event, but my issue is - i want Loading functionality as Greensock's LoaderMAX is providing. like we can append our loading items into queue and after that loading all the items one by one and displaying progress report of whole queue not for single item. check out this http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/

Comment: only problem with LoaderMAX is that it works only with URLRequest not with fileref.load or Loader.loadBytes.